# How to fix broken html in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I have a html as a string. In my code I substring it and it my code I get something like:

```
<div>loremlalal..<p>dsdM</p> - that's all
```

How can I parse the html so I get the correct output?

Maybe you know some packages I can use.

I saw one answer here on stackoverflow and it used `document` object but since I use next.js I will be having problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to dom directly like this way.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<h1>Hello world..</h1>'}}></div>
```